# How to fix "Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor" error?

Tags: typescript, typescript-class

I am having a problem with these classes. I want to use the method `doSomething()` exclusive to class `B` without type casting it every time, but when I specify property `a` to be of type `B`, it tells me that it is not assigned in the constructor, which is somewhat false as the parent constructor does the assignment.

```ts
class A {

}

class B extends A {
  doSomething() { }
}

class One {
  constructor(protected a: A){  }
}

class Two extends One {
  protected a: B // Property 'a' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

  constructor(){
    super(new B());
    // If I enter "this.a = new B();" here then the error disappears, but the code is redundant.
  }

  doStuff() {
    this.a.doSomething()
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQSC%20LSRgIWgUwA8AXPAOwBMZ5lppyB7AZXoFs8iALAS1IHMAKAJSJo6dEkxRoAeVJ5ESWsHqkIRAE4BXYEXrr%20AB3X0SOvOWhgAXHEEJaYjOCkAVAO718xMpRlyFtEYmeGYW1tC4APSR0AAKxgZ46kQAntAA5GDp0ByQ0KSePFxEXGAgXABeSZYU0FwwBUR0eABmRSQgaVhcvHIWPNCc8sqqGtq66gB0KEoqalo6ekI0tNAQmon6cm4RQoIA3Iqr0dAAki1n%20KQk6tAARJz1k2DQALz5eDvYQvt3OUnyIakQYceRJYy3cj1MAGRJgdQQAA00AARpomkNoMpyPJ6tB1OZNBQwNdpg4ZnQmERNC0WkIAqtHhBnpMGMw2I8%20EIjmIgA)

Comment: You say the parent constructor does the assignment, but no assignment happens in the parent class constructor in the code you provided. Which one is true? P.s. Please do not add irrelevant tags.

Comment: In typescript, constructor(protected a: A){  } is shorthand for constructor (a: A) {  this.a = a; }

Comment: Yeah, but why did you expect it to not error in strict mode (I know the emitted code is `constructor(a) { this.a = a; }`) then? In addition to jcalz's answer, you can use [definite assignment assertions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20166#issue-153719746) for that, seems like a [good case](https://tsplay.dev/mA7vXw) for one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the proposal for adding [class field declarations](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#class-field-declarations-for-javascript) to JavaScript has different semantics from what you might expect and what TypeScript designers expected when they added them to TypeScript.  It turns out that in JavaScript, class field declarations will be initialized via [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and not by assignment, and all such declared fields without initializers will be initalized with `undefined`.  So eventually you can expect code like yours to generate JavaScript that sets `a` to `undefined` in the subclass even though your intention is just to narrow the type from the base class.  Blecch.

So, in TypeScript 3.7, [a `--useDefineForClassFields` flag was added, along with the `declare` property modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier).  If you use `--useDefineForClassFields`, the compiler will output code that is compliant with the expected `Object.defineProperty()` semantics for class fields:

And if you [run your code as-is with that flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQSC+LSRgIWgUwA8AXPAOwBMZ5lppyB7AZXoFs8iALAS1IHMAKAJSJo6dEkxRoAeVJ5ESWsHqkIRAE4BXYEXrr+AB3X0SOvOWhgAXHGEJRaDOCkAVAO718xMpRlyFtEYmeGYW1tC4APSR0AAKxgZ46kQAntAA5GDp0ByQ0KSePFxEXGAgXABeSZYU0FwwBUR0eABmRSQgaVhcvHIWPNCc8sqqGtq66gB0KEoqalo6ekIBtNAQmon6cm4RQoIA3Iqr0dAAki1n+KQk6tAARJz1k2DQALz5eDvYQvt3OUnyIakQYceRJYy3cj1MAGRJgdQQAA00AARpomkNoMpyPJ6tB1OZNBQwNdprRxLQGIwiJoWi1ljRVo8IM9JlTWOxuHwhEcxChttB3PQhGymDS6UIgA), you'll see the issue at runtime:

```
new Two().doStuff()
// [ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:" 
// [ERR]: this.a is undefined
```

The solution is to use the `declare` property modifier to narrow the subclass property without emitting any corresponding `Object.defineProperty()` code:

```
class Two extends One {
  declare protected a: B // okay

  constructor() {
    super(new B());
  }

  doStuff() {
    this.a.doSomething()
  }
}

new Two().doStuff(); // okay now
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQSC+LSRgIWgUwA8AXPAOwBMZ5lppyB7AZXoFs8iALAS1IHMAKAJSJo6dEkxRoAeVJ5ESWsHqkIRAE4BXYEXrr+AB3X0SOvOWhgAXHGEJRaDOCkAVAO718xMpRlyFtOR4mOryRibBJBbW0LgA9HHQ9ADWYACeKEoqalo6ekIBtNAQmgZ4+nJusUKCANyKDg0MjESaAGZtBTRFnFwQAHRg-c2s7Nx8Qg1iKJXQ7vRCw0ytHQUJ0KSe5cbqQA)