# How to define $refs and $root type in Vuejs with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-class-components

I am using Vue3(class type components) with typescript. Please find below code

```
export default class MyClassextends Vue {
  $refs!: {
    locationSearch: any;
  };
  $root!: {
    $on: any;
  };
}
```

`locationSearch` is a reference of an element. I am getting below error:

```
Property '$refs' will overwrite the base property in 'Vue<unknown, {}, {}>'. If this is intentional, add an initializer. Otherwise, add a 'declare' modifier or remove the redundant declaration.
```

One fix I did was that I used ref elements like `this.$refs.locationSearch as any` but i think it is not a better solution. Same error for $root.
Can you help how to typecast those properties.

Can anyone knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after upgrading to a new TypeScript version (4.3+) which has some breaking changes: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#breaking-changes

So in your `tsconfig.json` you need to set the `useDefineForClassFields=false` to make it work again (without the need to change your code).

This answer elaborates on the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66555044/1572330
But just using `declare public $refs:{ ... };` broke my code at runtime, so this won't work with Vue specific code!